# IOS view delegates and when they are called

Tags: ios, delegates, uiviewcontroller

I have an iPhone app with three views, a switcher view, a data acquisition view, and a data summary view.  When the app starts up, the viewDidLoad delegate for the switcher view is called, and then the viewDidLoad delegate for the data acquisition view is called TWICE, followed by a viewWillDisappear call and a dealloc for the data acquisition view.  Both calls originate from the same line of code in my switcher view which is when I invoke insertSubView for the data acquisition view.  One call is from UIViewController and one is from UINib which is also called by UIViewController.  Does this make any sense?

Then, when I take user input to change views, the viewWillDisappear delegate for the data acquisition view is NOT called.  I just get the viewDidLoad call for the data summary view.

I'm confused.  I am trying to use viewWillDisappear to write out data from the data acquisition view that can then be read into the data summary view, but given this sequence it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions:1)Are your three views using separate view controllers? 2)What is the basic function of the acquisition view, ie network access or user interaction? 3)What was the switcher view doing in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I have three separate view controllers (a switch view controller, a data acquisition view controller with lots of buttons to gather data from the user, and a view summary controller that reports out on the data.  The switcher view just manages a tab at the bottom of the window to swap between the other two views.

Comment: Updated based answer based on that comment.

Answer (score 0):

To address what seems to be your last/main concern. NO [DataAcquisitionView viewWillDisappear] is not where to populate your SummaryView. When you finish loading you data you should then expressly create your summaryView, then populate it views with whatever you need to summarize, and then present it.

Based on you new information:

You want to use the tabBarController delegate method;

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    NSLog(@"Switch views");
}
```

That will tell you we the user has selected a different viewController you can the handle that event.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand your answer.  The question is when to trigger writing out the data from the data acquisition view so that it can be read back in to the data summary view when that view loads.  How do I know that the data acquisition view is about to disappear?